# Haskell null main function

Tags: haskell

I'm using a junk.hs file just to load in ghci.  I'm not using my main  function, just calling other functions in the file to test them out, eg:

```
-- junk.hs
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "hello"

otherFunction a b = a + b
```

When I load:

```
Prelude> :l junk.hs
Prelude> otherFunction 1 2  -- good
```

This is fine, since I'm not calling main, and since I have to define some main function this does the job.

However, what would be the correct minimal, null main function?

I tried

```
main :: IO ()
main = Nothing
```

And this failed

```
*Main> :load junk.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( junk.hs, interpreted )

junk.hs:2:8: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘IO ()’ with actual type ‘Maybe a0’
    • In the expression: Nothing
      In an equation for ‘main’: main = Nothing
  |
2 | main = Nothing
  |        ^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Comment: Can't you just not define a `main` at all?

Comment: Hmm, now that I try that, I guess I can.  Sorry, I thought /some/ main was a requirement.

Comment: Only if you want to create an executable (and in that case you will care about what `main` does)

Comment: As @sepp2k said, you don't need a `main` for a library. But I feel that someone should answer the question asked: the reason you got that error is because `Nothing` has type `Maybe a` (for any `a`), but you have said that `main` is of type `IO ()`. These are not the same type! A minimal `main` would actually be `main = return ()`; this simply returns `()` without doing anything.

Comment: `Nothing` is a literal of type `Maybe a` (as your error message suggests), it's a completely distinct monad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Nothing` has type `Maybe a` for some `a`, but never `IO ()`. So this can't be a value for `main`.

The standard no-op `main` action is

```
main :: IO ()
main = return ()
```

This can be executed just fine, and just do... well, *nothing*.

Alternatively, if you *don't* want the main action to be executable silently, you can make it

```
main :: IO ()
main = error "This program should not be run."
```

or something similar.

One of the *shortest* options would be

```
main=main::IO()
```

which would either loop forever or crash with infinite-recursion error. Needless to say, don't do this unless you're feeling *really* lazy and know nobody else will have to deal with that code...

Comment: *Almost* as short: `main=mempty::IO()`. If you need `Control.Applicative` or `Control.Monad` anyway, you can use `empty::IO()` or `mzero::IO()`, respectively, to get an uninformative exception.

Comment: If you happen to be using `PartialTypeSignatures`, you can shorten one character more: `main=mempty::_()`. I don't yet understand why a type signature is still needed when using `NoMonomorphismRestriction` with `ExtendedDefaultRules`.

Comment: @dfeuer I'm sure people on Codegolf.SE would give much shorter solutions yet, but...

Answer (score 2):

To answer my question, it looks like I could do:

```
main :: IO ()
main = undefined
```

But as @sepp2k pointed out, this is unnecessary.

Comment: This is unnecessary for your specific situation but `undefined` is good to know about, since it can be used for any funtion that needs to exist for the code to compile, but you don't want to implement it yet.  For example, the function is only used in one code branch, and you are currently working on the other branch.